# change UITabBar.appearance().tintColor at runtime

Tags: swift, uitabbar, color-picker

I want to allow the user to change the whole App-Color.
But whenever I select a color it is only changed after the App will be restarted.

Is there any option to change the color at runtime?

I've set up a `Button` with a function like this to create a `ColorPicker`

```
@IBAction func colorChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Initializing Color Picker
        let picker = UIColorPickerViewController()

        // Setting the Initial Color of the Picker
        picker.selectedColor = UIColor(named: "MyGreen")!

        // Setting Delegate
        picker.delegate = self

        // Presenting the Color Picker
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And when the user picked a color, I make the changes in this function

```
func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        defaults.set(viewController.selectedColor, forKey: "myColor")
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = viewController.selectedColor
    }
```

To change the color at startup I've implemented this in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        var myColor = defaults.color(forKey: "myColor")
        if  myColor == nil {
            myColor = UIColor(named: "MyGreen")
        }
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = myColor
        
        return true
    }
```

Comment: here is quote from apple doc "iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back." hope this will help you link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

Comment: Thanks for your information from apple doc, unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to remove a view and then put it back. Could you give me some code how this could look like? (I'm using storyboard if this is helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone gave me an Article to read how it can be done.
https://zamzam.io/protocol-oriented-themes-for-ios-apps/

I've ended up doing it like this:

```
 func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        defaults.set(viewController.selectedColor, forKey: "myColor")
        apply(for: UIApplication.shared, color: viewController.selectedColor)
    }
```

by adding this function

```
func apply(for application: UIApplication, color: UIColor) {
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = color
        application.windows.reload()
    }
```

and these extensions

```
public extension UIWindow {

    /// Unload all views and add back.
    /// Useful for applying `UIAppearance` changes to existing views.
    func reload() {
        subviews.forEach { view in
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            addSubview(view)
        }
    }
}

public extension Array where Element == UIWindow {
    
    /// Unload all views for each `UIWindow` and add back.
    /// Useful for applying `UIAppearance` changes to existing views.
    func reload() {
        forEach { $0.reload() }
    }
}
```

If it's good or not I don't know - but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

have you try using `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor` ?

Comment: Questions for the author belong better in comments to the post.

Comment: It's not that I'm using the wrong item which I want to change. It changes everything perfectly, but unfortunately only after I have restarted the app.